# Documenting Rcpp module exposed methods with roxygen2

Tags: r, rcpp

I have an Rcpp module in my package which, as well as exposing the class, exposes a number of methods. Is it possible to document the methods (on the C++ side) using roxygen2? My module looks like this:

```
RCPP_MODULE(BayesFst) {
using namespace Rcpp;

class_<BayesFst>( "BayesFst")
.default_constructor("Standard constructor")
.method("printData", &BayesFst::printData)
.method("printCounts", &BayesFst::printCounts)
.method("printInitialPvals", &BayesFst::printInitialPvals)
.method("printFstSummary", &BayesFst::printFstSummary)
.method("run", &BayesFst::run)
.method("setData", &BayesFst::setData)
.method("setPriorParameters", &BayesFst::setPriorParameters)
.method("setRunParameters", &BayesFst::setRunParameters)
.method("ldiriTest", &BayesFst::ldiriTest)
.property("interaction", &BayesFst::getInteraction, &BayesFst::setInteraction)
;
```

}

I would like to document all of these methods ideally. A simple idea is to hide the class behind wrapper functions and then call the methods from within R wrapper functions, but this feels kind of inelegant to me.

I have tried adding the roxygen comment lines to the functions, but because they don't get exported in the same way the documentation doesn't seem to get picked up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not be able to rely on Rcpp to carry the roxygen documentation over the way `compileAttributes()` would ... as you are not invoking `compileAttributes()`.

Feel free to construct (and test and then contribute :) a new helper function; otherwise I would just use roxygen in an R file and proceed from there.

*Edit:*  I also [filed an issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/617) so that we don't forget about it.

Comment: Is there anything new on that topic?

Comment: No, but contributions would be welcome. Probably better to discuss at [the issue ticket](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/617).

Comment: I wonder what "just use roxygen in an R file" means. Once the package is built, how can documentation be added later on?

Comment: Have you used `roxygen2`?  In essence, you make edits in the `R/` directory, call it and it writes and/or updates the `man/*Rd` files.  So this is like editing the code -- you alter the package preparation a new (minor or major release). Makes sense?  Many tools help too -- look at some tutorials.

Comment: roxygenize() fails at Rcpp::loadModule("myModule", TRUE) command in R file with error `Unable to load module "myModule": Failed to initialize module pointer`. R version 3.5.1, Rcpp_1.0.0, roxygen2_6.1.1 devtools_2.0.1